# Code to filter all http/https traffic on system...while my app is open

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-4.0, filter

I have an app where I need to filter all http/https traffic (web requests) on the entire system. Basically I want to give an administrator the ability to enter addresses/URLs onto a whitelist and then block and/or monitor everything else. This can happen only when my main app module is open, or it can happen at all times (via a Windows service.)

I know how to do everything except plug into the network sockets, inspect, and approve or cancel the requests. I've already done a lot of searching, and I'm not getting anywhere!

FYI, I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2012 (.NET Framework 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

From you description it seems like, what you need is a **`Firewall`**.

Checkout these articles

- [Useful Lite Effective Firewall .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17037/Useful-Lite-Effective-Firewall-NET)
- [Simple Packet - Filter Firewall](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5602/Simple-Packet-Filter-Firewall) (Not a .Net article)